# os-prober fail to find Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, grub

I got 2 hard drives

- Samsung nvme SSD (Linux)
- Kingston SSD (Windows 10)

Boot options:

- Storage: UEFI
- Fast Boot: Disabled

[Firmware options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4xsf.jpg)

[Boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V24wq.jpg)

### This is working:

Fist I installed Arch Linux to Samsung nvme SSD. You can see the `GRUB` loader in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4xsf.jpg) image. After that, I installed Windows 10. I have seen some comments about Windows EFI partition. But Windows 10 does not create an EFI partition. As you can seen in the image, There is a Windows boot record in Samsung nvme SSD (Windows is installed on Kingston SSD).

Now, I can load both Windows and Linux by selecting respective boot device from the [boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V24wq.jpg). When I load Linux and repair the boot loader, `os-prober` will detect Windows partition and grub will add it to the menu. It will load Windows without any issue.

### This is NOT working:

If I install Windows first and Linux after, `os-prober` can't find Windows 10.

NOTE:

- In all above cases I disabled Windows 10 fast startup option.
- In all above cases I made sure both operating systems are using UEFI
- I installed Windows and Linux multiple times to make sure this behavior is consistent

Why `os-prober` failed to find Windows partition when Windows is installed first?